# Rotating SplitViewController messes up toolbar in master view

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a SplitViewController.  In the master view I have a toolbar that is attached to the status bar.

When I launch the app in landscape mode (master view is visible), it looks great:

[image]

I launch in portrait:
[image]

After launching in portrait I rotate the screen to landscape.  The master view appears as it should, but the toolbar is no longer attached to the status bar.

[image]

As you can see the toolbar is too small now and runs into the status bar.  I have the delegate setup correctly to tell the toolbar to attach to the status bar.  This problem only seems to happen when I start the device in portrait and rotate it.

I have tried to force the master view to re-layout by calling setNeedsLayout in viewWillAppear but that makes no difference.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but make sure that in your view controllers that this is set appropriately:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO
}
```

Comment: Yeah bummer no luck.  The status bar never ends up being hidden.  Its just that the toolbar stops obeying the fact that it should be attached to the status bar and flow underneath it.  IE toolbar and status bar should be 64 in height, but after rotate they smash together and end up only being 44 in height.

Comment: I have the same issue, but it's usually fine and happens only when I rotate screen quickly landscape and portrait.